# Programming a XM1000 Sensor Device in C Programming Language Need if statement

Tags: c, if-statement, sensors, contiki

I am programming a sensor mote (XM1000) I am using Contiki Operating System to program this devices ( I am using terminal to view the outputs and GEdit to write my 'C' code in. This sensor mote has a temprature, light and humidity sensor on board as well as 3 LED lights.

Below I have two sets of code. The first set of code functions and gives me the sensor readings for the values for temprature, light and humidity.

The second set of code functions. it turns the LED lights on/off and makes them blinking regularly on the sensor node XM1000, it counts how many times the LED has blinked and output the count to the console.

The problem I am having is creating a if statement to meet these following conditions and I am struggling to combine the two codes together. So this is what I want to achieve:

•   If the temperature exceeds over 26 Degrees then turn on LED Light 1 for 5 seconds, else if the temperature is equal to and below 26 Degrees then turn off LED Light 1.

•   If the Humidity exceeds over 40% then turn on LED Light 2 for 5 seconds, else if the humidity is equal to and below 40% then turn off LED Light 2.

•   If the Light intensity exceeds over 510 nanometres then turn on LED Light 3 for 5 seconds, else if the light intensity is equal to and below 510nm then turn off LED Light 3.

First Set of Code: It measures the temprature, light and humidity and outputs the results on a terminal window.

```
    #include "contiki.h" //Contiki Header File 
    #include "dev/light-sensor.h" //Light Sensor Header File 
    #include "dev/sht11-sensor.h" //Temperature and Humidity Header File 

    #include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */ // standard input/output library needed to write to the standard output

    static struct etimer timer; //Process Requires a Timer 
    int light=0, temp=0, humid=0;

    //To Start

    /*___________________________________________________*/

    PROCESS(sensor_reading_process, "Sensor Reading Process");
    AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&sensor_reading_process);

    /*___________________________________________________*/

    //PROCESS BEGINS 

    PROCESS_THREAD(sensor_reading_process, ev, data)
   {
     PROCESS_BEGIN();

     SENSORS_ACTIVATE(light_sensor); //Activate the Light Sensor
     SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);//Activate Temp/Humidity Sensor

     etimer_set(&timer, CLOCK_CONF_SECOND);//Configuring Timer 1SEC

     while(1) {  //Start of While Loop 

     PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev==PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER);//Wait4Time


    // This is how we get the Sensor Values for light, temp, hum
    light = light_sensor.value(LIGHT_SENSOR_PHOTOSYNTHETIC);
    temp = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);
    humid = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_HUMIDITY);

    printf("Light=%d, Temp=%d, Humid=%d\n", light, temp, humid); 
    //Above Line if Print Plus Values 
    etimer_reset(&timer); //Reset the Timer 

    }

    PROCESS_END(); //End of Process
     }
```

The second code:

```
    #include "contiki.h" 
    #include "leds.h"  // LED HEADER FILE 
    #include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */ 
    static struct etimer timer; 
    /*____________________________________________________*/ 
    PROCESS(led_blinking_process, "LED Blinking Process"); 
    PROCESS(LED_process, "LED process"); 
    AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&LED_process); 
    /*____________________________________________________*/ 


     PROCESS_THREAD(LED_process, ev, data) 
     { 
     static int count = 0; 
     PROCESS_BEGIN(); 
     etimer_set(&timer, CLOCK_CONF_SECOND/2); // 0.5S timer 
     leds_init(); // initialise the LEDs 
     while(1) { 
     PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev==PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER); // wait for timer             event 
    count++; // count the blinking times 
    process_start(&led_blinking_process, NULL); // to blink the BLUE Led 
    printf("Count: %d\n", count); // output the counter number to console 
    etimer_reset(&timer); // reset the timer 
    } 
    PROCESS_END(); 
    } 


    CODE FOR LED LIGHTS 

    /*____________________________________________________*/ 
    PROCESS_THREAD(led_blinking_process, ev, data) 
    { 
    PROCESS_BEGIN(); 
    leds_toggle(LEDS_BLUE); // Blinking the Blue LED 
    PROCESS_END(); 
    }
```

Please note both codes work when I run them , I am just trying to combine them , use a if statement so i can meet my functions I have stated above.

Thanks in advance for any help or contributions!

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/if_else_statement_in_c.htm

Comment: Is it your intention that everything works on these 5 second marks? That is, every five seconds you read the humidity, light, etc. and set the lights? Or did you want the conditions to be tested more frequently?

Comment: Just for testing purposes I have done it for 5 seconds, it can be more or less, i am basically trying to impelment a watering system, where if the conditions are met , then the LED will switch on which represents a water sprinkler @AustinHastings

Comment: Next question: what are the units returned by the various sensors? Are they the same as your desired conditions? That is, if I query the light sensor, is it going to return an integer number in nanometers, or something else?

Comment: "If Light intensity exceeds over 510 nanometers" - first time I heard that light intensity is measured in nanometers. What does that even mean?

Comment: So.... you wrote all this code and you're struggling with an 'if' ? Hmmm...

Comment: You're overcomplicating things. You don't need separate `led_blinking_process` and `LED_process` - merge them in one. (You can even do everything in `sensor_reading_process` itself.) If you choose to keep 2 processes, add the line `process_poll(&LED_process);` in the sensors process to signal the LED process that sensors have just been read.

Comment: I will eventually convert them into degrees using "0.01 * sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP) - 39.6;" , @AustinHastings I have converted them , the light and humidity are displayed as normal figures eg 634 , 234

Comment: @kfx the sensor measures light in nanometers , check the spec for the xm1000 http://www.advanticsys.com/shop/asxm1000-p-24.html

Comment: Jasjoot, the `nm` refers to the peak spectral sensitivity (light is electromagnetic waves with a specific wavelength) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum#Visible_radiation_.28light.29  What the sensors measure is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance adjusted for the sensors' spectral sensitivity curves, which is measured in watts-per-square-unit.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion caused . When I run my first script , it shows me readings such as :    Light= 209 , Temp=6680 , Humid = 734 , it updates every second  and the figures are near enough the same

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think it will look like, give or take a little hacking. I've structured the code as a single loop, that just polls all three sensors at 5 second intervals. So every 5 seconds, the on/off status of all three lights might change. I figure for watering a lawn, you don't really need split-second precision in terms of knowing when it got hot, or dark, or whatever.

Based on your replies in the comments section of the OP, there might have to be some computation done involving the return values of the sensor readings. I figure it's probably easier to do the computation at compile time, so the code is biased that way.

```
#include <stdio.h> /* for printf() */ 

#include "contiki.h" 
#include "leds.h"
#include "dev/light-sensor.h"
#include "dev/sht11-sensor.h"

PROCESS(Led_management_process, "LED Management Process"); 
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&Led_management_process); 

static struct etimer Timer; 

/* Per the online docs at http://www.advanticsys.com/wiki/index.php?title=TestCM5000

     T = -39.6 + 0.01 × SO(T)

So, solving for SOt gives:
*/
#define degreesC(n) (n)

#define TEMP_D1 degreesC(-39.6)
#define TEMP_D2 degreesC(0.01)
#define TEMP_THRESHOLD(tempC) (int)(((((double)(tempC))-(TEMP_D1))/(TEMP_D2)))

#define TARGET_TEMP_READING  TEMP_THRESHOLD(degreesC(26))

#define LIGHT_LED LEDS_GREEN
#define HUM_LED   LEDS_BLUE
#define TEMP_LED  LEDS_RED

PROCESS_THREAD(Led_management_process, ev, data) 
{ 
    static int humidity_led_on = 0;
    static int light_led_on = 0;
    static int temp_led_on = 0;

    PROCESS_BEGIN();
    SENSORS_ACTIVATE(light_sensor);
    SENSORS_ACTIVATE(sht11_sensor);
    leds_init();

    unsigned int cycle = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("%8u:", cycle);

        /* This part is questionable, since I don't know if the 
           sensors are guaranteed to return ints (vs. floats or
           something) and I don't know what units they use. */
        int temp = sht11_sensor.value(SHT11_SENSOR_TEMP);

        if (temp > TARGET_TEMP_READING) {
            printf(" TEMP warm- ");
            if (!temp_led_on) {
                printf("toggle LED");
                temp_led_on = 1;
                leds_toggle(TEMP_LED);
            }
            else {
                printf("LED is ok ");
            }
        }
        else {
            printf(" TEMP cold- ");
            if (temp_led_on) {
                printf("toggle LED");
                temp_led_on = 0;
                leds_toggle(TEMP_LED);
            }
            else {
                printf("LED is ok ");
            }
        }

        /* Code for humidity */
        /* Code for light */

        printf("\n");

        /* Sleep 5 seconds */
        etimer_set(&Timer, CLOCK_CONF_SECOND * 5);
        PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(ev==PROCESS_EVENT_TIMER);
        etimer_reset(&Timer);
        ++cycle;
    }

    PROCESS_END(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am going to give that a try now !

Comment: It has come back with errors     1) error 'Timer' undeclared (first use in this function)   2) note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in   3) warning: unused variable 'temp_led_on'    4) warning: unused variable 'humidity_led_on

Comment: I've modified this to show the calculation for temperature. I think it's probably better to perform the math at compile time. I don't know why the Timer is giving you an error - did you get the declaration? It's near the top. The unused variables are for you to fill in, obviously. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Austin Hastings , I just feel like this is getting way more complicated for me and i feel lost , I am fairly new to programming language C. :(((

Comment: A number of problems in the answer that are visible even without trying the code: `timer` is going to be undefined, so the code won't even compile; in  `PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL` you should also check whether `etimer_expired(&Timer)` returns true; `cycle` will always be equal to 0.

Comment: Okay, fixed the `timer` ->`Timer` thing. What's with checking `etimer_expired`? That's not part of the sample code (and I'm just gluing together his code bits - I don't have one of these devices nor could I find any useful docs).